# Symbol not found: 'bereq.is_bgfetch' (expected type BOOL)

Tags: varnish

I am certainly doing something wrong or I am missing something because it is driving me crazy.

I am using Varnish 6

in defautl.vcl, I am trying to not cache 5xx errors and preserve the existing cache

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
...
    if (beresp.status >= 500) {
        if (bereq.is_bgfetch) {
            return (abandon);
        }
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }
...

}
```

and I got `Symbol not found: 'bereq.is_bgfetch' (expected type BOOL)` when I try to restart varnish

Should I set is_bgfetch somewhere or is is_bgfetch deprecated and there is another way to do the above ?

Comment: `bereq.is_bgfetch` is readily available in all modern versions of Varnish. Can you remove that statement from your VCL, restart Varnish and then share the exact Varnish version you're running. You can get the version string by running the `varnishadm` command. The second line after the banner has the version string. Before we start debugging, I'd like to know whether you're really using a modern version of Varnish or not.

Comment: thanks @ThijsFeryn here is the version varnish-4.0.5 revision 07eff4c29
I thought I had version because I have tried installing from version 6 source code and it didn't work so I installed the rpm and it looks like it is version 4. You are right, I guess is_bgfetch shoould be available on version 5+ ?

Comment: That's it indeed. I would encourage you to upgrade to a more recent version. I'll post an "official" answer to your question that contains the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments we can conclude that you're using a deprecated version of Varnish that doesn't support `bereq.is_bgfetch` yet.

I would urge you to upgrade your Varnish installation to a recent & supported version.

Please have a look at https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/quick-start/, which describes how to easily install the LTS version of Varnish using packages.

If you want to latest *fresh* version of Varnish instead of the LTS version, please have a look at the packages on https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/varnish74

Once you've upgrade to 6.0 LTS or 7.4 (which is currently the latest *fresh* version), you should have access to `bereq.is_bgfetch`.

Comment: upgraded to 7.4.2 and the symbol is now being found. Actually it can be found starting from 5.2+ https://varnish-cache.org/docs/5.2/whats-new/upgrading-5.2.html